# Choose a specific row of a recyclerview for sharing intent

Tags: android, mysql, android-recyclerview

Is there a way to choose a specific row of my `RecyclerView` (maybe by getting the index of the row) and then use it to create an intent.

I tried some things by getting the specific row information but that was not even close. My recycler is populated with data from a database.

Comment: Yeah create an onItemClickListener interface to interact between your Activity and your RecyclerView.Adapter, [a tutorial for this](https://antonioleiva.com/recyclerview-listener/)

Comment: Please post your activity and the recycler adapter

Answer (score 0):

To choose a specific row of my recycler, you can add setOnItemClickListener code like this one to your onCreate function:

```
listView_search.setOnItemClickListener(
            new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id){
                    //Here I'm getting store_id and store_name
                    TextView store_search_id =(TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.store_search_id);
                    TextView store_search_name =(TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.store_search_name);
                    String store_name = store_search_name.getText().toString();
                    String store_id = store_search_id.getText().toString();

                    //Then I'm sending theses variables to a shared Intent
                    Intent myIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), StoresShowActivity.class);
                    myIntent.putExtra("STORE_ID", store_id);
                    myIntent.putExtra("STORE_NAME", store_name);
                    startActivity(myIntent);
            }
            }
);
```

You may also want to follow these steps:

A. Add a layout for the Recycle view:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_stores_search"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="ksa.ikp.activities.StoresSearchActivity">

<SearchView
    android:id="@+id/SearchView_store"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:iconifiedByDefault="false">

    <requestFocus />
</SearchView>

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView_search"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/SearchView_store" />
</RelativeLayout >
```

B. Add a layout for the recycleview item

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:padding="10dp">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/store_search_id"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="invisible" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/store_search_name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/store_search_category"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

C. Use adapter like this one and you can modify it based on your need

```
public class StoresSearchAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

// Declare Variables
Context mContext;
LayoutInflater inflater;
private List<Store> myList = null;
private ArrayList<Store> myArrayList;

public StoresSearchAdapter(Context context, List<Store> myList) {
    mContext = context;
    this.myList = myList;
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
    this.myArrayList = new ArrayList<Store>();
    this.myArrayList.addAll(myList);
}

public class ViewHolder {
    TextView store_search_id;
    TextView store_search_name;
    TextView store_search_category;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return myList.size();
}

@Override
public Store getItem(int position) {
    return myList.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public View getView(final int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
    final ViewHolder holder;
    if (view == null) {
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_stores_search_item, null);
        // Locate the TextViews in activity_stores_search_item.xml
        holder.store_search_id = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.store_search_id);
        holder.store_search_name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.store_search_name);
        holder.store_search_category = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.store_search_category);
        view.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
    }
    // Set the results into TextViews
    holder.store_search_id.setText(myList.get(position).getStr_id()+"");
    holder.store_search_name.setText(myList.get(position).getStr_name());
    String s = SplashActivity.db.getNameById(myList.get(position).getStr_cat_id()+"",SplashActivity.db.TABLE_CATEGORY,SplashActivity.db.COLUMN_CAT_NAME,SplashActivity.db.COLUMN_CAT_ID);
    s = " in ("+ s + ")";
    holder.store_search_category.setText(s);
    return view;
}

// Filter Class
public void filter(String s) {
    s = s.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
    myList.clear();
    if (s.length() == 0) {
        myList.addAll(myArrayList);
    } else {
        myList.addAll(SplashActivity.db.getAllStoresFiltered(s));
    }
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

}

Finally your final output will be something like this one:
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wc7tl.png)

Comment: Where is the Interface or any RecyclerView.Adapter code? he isn't going to solve his problem with you just posting the implementation of onItemClickListener Interface without any further code

Answer (score 0):

This is my recyclerbackgroundtask

public class RecycleBackgroundTask extends AsyncTask{

```
Context ctx;
Activity activity;
RecyclerView recyclerView;
RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;
RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
ArrayList<Post> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();

public RecycleBackgroundTask(Context ctx){
    this.ctx = ctx;
    activity = (Activity)ctx;
}

String json_string = "http://192.168.2.110/app/post.php";

@Override
public void onPreExecute() {
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView)activity.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(ctx);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    adapter = new RecyclerAdapter(arrayList);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
}

@Override
public Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
    try {
        URL url = new URL(json_string);
        HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
        InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        String line;

        while ((line=bufferedReader.readLine())!=null) {
            stringBuilder.append(line+"\n");
        }
        httpURLConnection.disconnect();
        String json_string = stringBuilder.toString().trim();

        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(json_string);
        JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("server_response");

        int count = 0;
        while(count<jsonArray.length()){
            JSONObject JO = jsonArray.getJSONObject(count);
            count++;

            Post post = new Post(JO.getString("headline"),JO.getString("source"),JO.getString("url"));
            publishProgress(post);

        }

        Log.d("JSON STRING",json_string);

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}


@Override
public void onProgressUpdate(Post... values) {

    arrayList.add(values[0]);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

And my RecyclerAdapter

public class RecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter {

```
private static final int TYPE_HEAD = 0;
private static final int TYPE_LIST = 1;



ArrayList<Post> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();

public RecyclerAdapter (ArrayList<Post> arrayList){

    this.arrayList = arrayList;
}



@Override
public RecyclerViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    if(viewType == TYPE_HEAD){
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row_recycler,parent,false); // instead of row_recycler ,header_layout.
        RecyclerViewHolder recyclerViewHolder = new RecyclerViewHolder(view,viewType);
        return recyclerViewHolder;
    }
    if(viewType == TYPE_LIST){
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row_recycler,parent,false);
        RecyclerViewHolder recyclerViewHolder = new RecyclerViewHolder(view,viewType);
        return recyclerViewHolder;
    }
    return null;

}



@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerViewHolder holder, int position) {


    if(holder.viewType == TYPE_LIST) {
        Post post = arrayList.get(position-1);
        holder.Headline.setText(post.getHeadline());
        holder.Source.setText(post.getSource());
        //holder.Url.setText(post.getUrl());


    }
}


@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return arrayList.size()+1;
}

public  static class RecyclerViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{

    TextView Headline,Source;//,Url;
    int viewType;



    public RecyclerViewHolder(View view,int viewType){

        super(view);
        if(viewType == TYPE_LIST) {
            Headline = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.headline);
            Source = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.source);

            Headline.setOnClickListener(this);
            Source.setOnClickListener(this);
           // Url = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.url);


            this.viewType = TYPE_LIST;

        }else if (viewType == TYPE_HEAD){

            this.viewType = TYPE_HEAD;
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "ITEM PRESSED = " + String.valueOf(getAdapterPosition()), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
@Override
public  int getItemViewType(int position){
    if(position==0)
        return TYPE_HEAD;
        return TYPE_LIST;


}

public  void setFilter(ArrayList<Post> newList){
    arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    arrayList.addAll(newList);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

}

Maybe that helps. i already set up a simple onclicklistener with a toast btw

Comment: btw ignore some useless stuff inside, its a "try" version